# pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have read streaming data and then I tried to apply StringIndexer on the values of a column. But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/IdeaProjects/trial2/module1/pgm1.py", line 90, in <module>
    indexed_df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
  File "/home/user/IdeaProjects/trial2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 205, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/home/user/IdeaProjects/trial2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 381, in _fit
    java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
  File "/home/user/IdeaProjects/trial2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 378, in _fit_java
    return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
  File "/home/user/IdeaProjects/trial2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/home/user/IdeaProjects/trial2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

Here is my code:

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", servers).option("subscribe", "ipfix").option("kafka.group.id",groupid).option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1000) \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false").load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").select(from_json(col("value"), jsonSchema).alias("parsed_data")).select("parsed_data.*") \
    .select("ab2","cc4")
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="cc4", outputCol="cc4_new")
indexed_df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
query = indexed_df.writeStream \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .format("console") \
        .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I am using writeStream.start() as shown above. However the error is still raised. Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think you can't fit a `StringIndexer` on the stream DataFrame. You need to use a batch DataFrame for it. Once fitted, you can use it to transform stream data.